# This code is supposed to reject pin codes that aren't 4 digits or 6, and its supposed to reject codes that have letters in them

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, letter

The code rejects pins with letters which it's supposed to do, but it rejects valid pins.  Below is the code can you see where I went wrong.

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
    let letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (pin.match(letters)) {
      return false;
      if (pin.length = 4 || 6) 
      return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `= ! ==` you have a typo in your code, use comparison not assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in checking the value, your if is missing a `}` and your regex is checking if there is any letter at the start and finish of the pin, it should check if it has any letters

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
let letters = /[A-Za-z]/;
  if (pin.match(letters)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```